# Django :Cant find the args when not using the non-named groups in urls.py

Tags: python, django

Here is the code in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^meta/\d{4}/$',metadata),
)
```

And in the view.py, i just simply print the request or args:

```
def metadata(request,*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse(str(args))
    #return HttpResponse(str(request))
```

the problem is that no matter I use the request or the args, I cant not get the **'year'** arg. 
For example, when i type url:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/meta/1990/` , it should return **1990**, However it does not.
According to the Django book, using non-named groups will return args correctly.
Btw, if i use named-groups, it works fine, args are saved in the kwargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put brackets around the part of the regular expression that you want to capture. For e.g.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^meta/(\d{4})/$',metadata),
)
```